# Different Performance while Select a view in oracle

Tags: oracle, performance, view

i try to tune an existing View. I'm sorry for not posting an example but i failed to replicate the Problem. And i can't understand the behavior.
My View (View A) based on another view (View b) and a Table (Table C). In the select list some fields of these and some Package calls are used.
The runtime of a specific Select is nearly 32 seconds.
I analyzed the Statement and startet to optimize View b. I droped all columns i don't need in View a and reduced the overhead of the View b. 
After this the select on View a was 5 seconds faster. I executed the select multiple times to get a valid average execute time, to be sure.
A Few minutes later i axecuted the Statement again and i got 32 Seconds. I executed this multiple times but it won't become faster.

There is no trafic on this database, the amount of data didn't change. And this is, until now, the first statement i have problems with getting reasonable results will analyzing the statment.
The Explainplan, I watched first, looks fine. No Full Table Scan (I know FTS is not overall bad). I have no idea why the executetime is so unstable, this made it hard to optimize the View and compare the results.

I think this sounds like a dump question, but i can't see the problem or have an idea what to do next.

Thanks and sorry for my bad english.

Comment: PL/SQL (package) function calls in any SELECT statement can be harmful to performance.  There is an overhead of context switching between SQL and PL/SQL on every call, and sometimes it is possible due to the way the query gets optimised that a function can be called thousands or millions of times even when the final result will only be a handful of rows.

Answer (score 0):

Unstable execute time

1) Did you clean up buffer cache between select statements?

2) In some situation you can improve your function and views with result_cacheing.  But you have to figure out if it is applicable for your problem? (long story about resultchahe)[http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/datawarehouse/vallath-resultcache-rac-284280.html]